# Drupal exposed form search term filter giving a SQL error

Tags: search

I had installed drupal 7 with oracle as database. Its working fine but some query fails. I am attaching the error that i got while searching a term with **search term** filter in my exposed filter form.

SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.created AS node_created, SUM(search_index.score * search_total.count) AS score, 'node' AS field_data_field_start_date_event_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_end_date_event_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_short_description_event_node_entity_type, 1 AS expression FROM {node} node LEFT JOIN {search_index} search_index ON node.nid = search_index.sid LEFT JOIN {search_total} search_total ON search_index.word = search_total.word WHERE (( (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (node.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) AND( (search_index.type = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND( (search_index.word = :db_condition_placeholder_3) )))) GROUP BY search_index.sid, SUM(search_index.score * search_total.count), node.nid, 'node', 'node', 'node', node.title, node.created HAVING (( (COUNT(*) >= :search_index_keys) ))) subquery (prepared: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.created AS node_created, SUM(search_index.score * search_total.count) AS score, 'node' AS L#953, 'node' AS L#954, 'node' AS L#955, 1 AS expression FROM "NODE" node LEFT JOIN "SEARCH_INDEX" search_index ON node.nid = search_index.sid LEFT JOIN "SEARCH_TOTAL" search_total ON search_index.word = search_total.word WHERE (( (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (node.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) AND( (search_index.type = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND( (search_index.word = :db_condition_placeholder_3) )))) GROUP BY search_index.sid, SUM(search_index.score * search_total.count), node.nid, 'node', 'node', 'node', node.title, node.created HAVING (( (COUNT(*) >= :search_index_keys) ))) subquery ) e: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 934 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here (/tmp/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:142) args: Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => event [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => abc [:search_index_keys] => 1 )

Is this a connection issue. My other filters in form works fine.

Comment: Drupal 7 natively supports MySQL, Postgres and sqlite.

Comment: there is a module for oracle though I have never tried it. https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle

Comment: My site is working fine with ORACLE. Issue is only with exposed form search term filter.

Comment: General error: 934 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here (/tmp/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:142) - Any idea about this error

Comment: search for 934 on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm